# Metrofit HTML/javascript applications to Windows 8 Metro?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

For most businesses it probably makes the most sense to write a tradtional HTML5/javascript applications and then port to the Windows 8 Metro hooks/apis.  As such, is there a tool that can automatically Metrofit your HTML5 web app?  (Note: the web application would likely need to be self-contained browser app without a traditional backend for it to work seamlessly).

Official "Migrating a Web app" Instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465143.aspx

Sample "Windows 8 Metro html5 / javascript" project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338916/Windows-8-JavaScript-Metro-Application-Getting-Sta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such tool. You will have to do all the grunt work yourself.

Comment: That appears to be a business opportunity - let's keep this active to see if tools begin to emerge